# SharePoint Online disable attachments for lists

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I disable the option to add attachments for lists on a 'site-collectional' level? So whenever new lists are created, anywhere within the site collection, the option to add attachments is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the list as a template with the setting set to off. Then you create new lists based on that template it will be set to 'disabled'.